# Why I cannot access prototype function (using closures)?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to create function findStrings which should share it's variables with the function init, stringSplit and stringSearch.

```
String.prototype.findStrings = (function () {
  var action = 'split';
  var params = ',';
  var init = function (action = 'split', params = ',') 
  { this.stringSplit(); }
  var stringSplit = function (action) 
  { return this.init(); }
 var stringSearch = function (action) 
  {return this.init(); }
  return init;
})();
```

What I need.
When I call `test.findStrings('split');` it should 1) initiate variables by calling init 2) then call stringSplit so *this* should be string *test*.

When I call `var result = test.findStrings( 'search', { params ... } );` 1) initiate variables, process arguments from object params 2) then call stringsSearch and *this* should be *test*.

```
var test = '#a > :matches(.b, #c)'; 
test.findStrings('split', "," );
var result = test.findStrings( 'search', { params ... } );
```

Error which I got is saying that *this* does not have stringSplit (because this is Window) and I need to *this* to be *test*.

How to access the *test* string within the functions and make it possible to access the variables and arguments within them?

Actually, I could remove the function searchStrings to simplify it.

**Solution:**

```
String.prototype.findStrings = (function () {
  var text = this;
...
String.prototype.init = function (action = 'split', params = ',') {
  text.stringSplit();
  }
}
```

There were two errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Why are you making it so complicated?

Comment: I have edited the code. I have tried var self = this; ... self.splitStrings() .. error splitString is not a function. ... 
 
stringSearch is planed to be recursive function which should use a lot of variables declared in findSeach. Because I want to share this variables I wanted to use a closure. The code is very shorten so I did not add the variables which are in complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to this to be test.

When `init()` is first called, `this` does equal `test`. The problem is that `stringSplit` and `stringSearch` are just variables, and have nothing to do with the current context.

Either way, the code is pretty difficult to understand. If you really want to override `String`, then why don't you do something like:

```
String.prototype.findStrings = function(action = 'split', params = ',') {
    // do logic here (not entirely sure what you want to accomplish)
    return (action === 'split') ? this.stringSplit() : this.stringSearch();
}

// Add other functions also to string prototype
String.prototype.stringSplit = function() { ... }
String.prototype.stringSearch = function() { ... }
```

---

Personally though, I don't like adding methods to types like `String` for various reasons. Why not adopt a more functional approach, and create functions that you simply pass strings to, and get an appropriate result?

For example:

```
function findStrings(str, params){
    // do logic and return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a circular reference in your code: the `init` function calls `stringSplit` which calls `init`.

But to reach to that problem you should remove the `this` keyword from your prototype function. `this` will get the value of the object that is calling your function, in your case the `window` object, but your functions are created in a closure so you can't access them using the `window` object.

Comment: The code is just a dummy. I have shortened the code as much as possible so the circular reference would be solved with conditions.